# How to create a typing combination where one of the types is provided as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I need a shorthand for a combination of types where one type is provided as an argument.

Example:

```py
class CustomType:
  pass

# Shorthand
  OptionalCustomType = Union[Optional[T], CustomType]

# Usage
  def fun(x: OptionalCustomType[str]) -> str:
    # Type of x should be equivalent to Union[None, CustomType, str]
    if x is None:
      return "None"
    if x is CustomType:
      return "Custom Type"
    return "Some string"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example basically works almost as-is. You just need to make `T` a typevar:

```py
from typing import Optional, Union, TypeVar

class CustomType:
    pass

T = TypeVar('T')
OptionalCustomType = Union[Optional[T], CustomType]

# This type-checks without an issue
def fun(x: OptionalCustomType[str]) -> str:
    # Type of x should be equivalent to Union[None, CustomType, str]
    if x is None:
        return "None"
    if x is CustomType:
        return "Custom Type"
    return "Some string"

y: OptionalCustomType[int]

# In mypy, you'll get the following output:
# Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.int, None, test.CustomType]'
reveal_type(y)
```

This particular technique is known as [generic type aliases](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-type-aliases).

Comment: Is this technique exclusive for mypy or is it the same for the `typing` module from the standard library? The reason I am asking is that I've been trying to get PyCharm to recognise my typing (similar to the example) without success and I know it uses the 'typing' module and the format from 'PEP 484`.

Comment: @Helgi -- There are examples of generic type aliases in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-aliases), so this should be something that's available in all Python type checkers. That said, it doesn't seem that Pycharm supports this yet -- I did a bit of digging, and found [an open issue about it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29257).